# Unable to load Bootstrap & Modal OffCanvas in Angular Application

Tags: typescript

I am trying to develop frontend for an Angular app with various Bootstrap Components. I copied the code given in Angular-Bootstrap component site and executed the same. But I am getting a datatype issue for 'content' parameter and hence unable to load the bootstrap.

1. I tried other error-free codes from YouTube and still Offcanvas or Modal components are not loading.
2. I want to reproduce whatever functionality the components are having as shown [ng-bootstrap](https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/components/offcanvas/examples)
3. Here is the error i face when i copy paste the code from ng-bootstrap site.
4. I have all the dependencies required; as mentioned in ng-bootstrap site.

> [My TypeScript File and the error; followed the same as the ng-bootstrap site](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5kJ92.png)

Comment: Just explicitly write `(content: any)`